# Phone number tagging with spaCy

Tags: named-entity-recognition, spacy

I have to do a BIO tagging for a given set of sentences.

For example:

```
sentence = 'My name is XYZ, I live in United States of America,
            my Phone number is (123)123-1234"
```

The phone number can be in any format.

The expected result:

[image]

But I get:

[image]

Code:

```
import spacy
s= 'I live in United states of America, my Phone number is (123)123-1234'
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(s)
test = pd.DataFrame([(e.text, e.pos_,e.ent_iob_,e.ent_type_) for e in doc])
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the wanted result you have given, you could use a simple regex like

```
^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$
```

which matches (as far as I have tested) nearly every phone number format. You can try it out at https://regexr.com/ to see if the pattern fits your data.

Then I would simply let that regex run over your data and categorise them, while removing the numbers from the text. Then you let spacy run over your cleaned up data and it should work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you're using using a pre-trained NER model to tag a single sentence.

- The pre-trained model is not especially trained for phone numbers, it performs general NER. This is why it will also tag persons/organization names, places, dates, etc. You could train a custom NER model but you need a large amount of data with phone numbers annotated.
- A single sentence is useful to debug but you must have at least a medium-size sample of data with phone numbers annotated in order to evaluate your method. A single sentence is not enough because it's normal for the system to make some errors, the point is to minimize the amount of errors on a representative sample.
- Finally it's important to consider alternatives to NER: phone numbers follow a quite specific format, it's probably more efficient to use some simple pattern-matching in this case.

Comment: While I buy spacy might not be the right solution for this problem, the pattern-matching here might not be simple... a phone number is 10, 11, 12, or 13 digits depending on which country codes (if any) are used, and these digits could be delimited with some combination of plus signs, parenthesis, dashes, dots, spaces, or no delimiters at all.

Answer (score 1):

### Pattern Matching

You can explicitly give Spacy patterns to use.

It turns out that identifying phone numbers in text is one of the [examples](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#example2) they give in their documents.

From the docs:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{"ORTH": "("}, {"SHAPE": "ddd"}, {"ORTH": ")"}, {"SHAPE": "ddd"},
           {"ORTH": "-", "OP": "?"}, {"SHAPE": "ddd"}]
matcher.add("PHONE_NUMBER", [pattern])

doc = nlp("Call me at (123) 456 789 or (123) 456 789!")
print([t.text for t in doc])
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(span.text)
```

Note that you'll have to give all the possible formats that you want to cover in the spacy format.

Potential formats include:

```
x(xxx) xxx-xxxx
xx xxx xxx xxxx
(xxx) xxx.xxxx
xxx-xxx-xxxx
xx xxx xxx xx xx
```

etc.